# Data not displaying from my database

Tags: c#, asp.net

It should be so freakin' easy, but why is my data not displaying? I even used the AccessDataSource wizard to configure the datasource and I still can't get it to show what is there. Here is my markup:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.mdb" 
SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Destinations FROM [Destinations]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:Label ID="CurrentDestLabel" runat="server" Text="What is currently displayed:" />
<br />
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Destinations") %>'/>
```

I don't get any errors or anything, just nothing displays for my "Label1". Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you bind your data source to the label? I mean is your label inside a formview, gridview, listview etc?

Comment: I put in a data source and then use the Eval function to bind it to the Label control, right?

Comment: No, that is not enough, you need to bind the data source. For that you need add the label inside a data bound control like repeater, formview, listview, gridview etc. Then assign your data source to the data bound control. Then your Eval function works

Comment: Ah, you are right. I need to put it inside a form view. Jeez, I hate that.

Comment: If you're just learning ASP .NET, I'd strongly recommend going with MVC over Webforms. Webforms is dying, because it tries to abstract far too much of what makes a web application a web application away from you. And a real database provider instead of Access.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but I think you try to show a whole List in a single label...
perhaps your command need something like "Select top 1 Destinations FROM [Destinations]"
So you make sure, that you have only one Element selected...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include any databound controls in a DetailsView, FormView, Gridview, etc...